# Display desired fragment on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer with a default fragment on create of the activity. For a specific fragment which has TableLayout with many columns I want to display in landscape mode. So I change the orientation on create of that fragment.

When I do that, the orientation changes, but the first default fragment is displayed. I guess this is because the activity's `onCreate()` is called again when the screen orientation changes and since I have the code to display the default fragment in the `onCreate()` the default fragment is displayed.

But I want my fragment with tablelayout to be displayed. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

think about using same fragment with different layout rather than using different fragment.

- add your desired layout in `res/layout-land` folder.
- check your current orientation in `onCreateView` & initialize your view & data according to it